# php: dynamic link appends content to existing page rather than opening new one

Tags: php, html

I have a dynamic link which fetches invoice detail based on invoice ID.

```
<a href='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>/retrieve?class=InvoiceLineItems&amp;id=<?php echo $invoice['invoice_id']; ?>'><?php echo $invoice['invoice_number']; ?></a>&nbsp;<?php echo $invoice['customer_name'] ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $invoice['invoice_date'] ?>
```

It calls this function

```
public function retrieve($class,
        $id = NULL)
{
    switch ($class) {
        case 'Invoice':
            $invoices = $this->invoice->getInvoices();
            include 'view/invoiceList.php';
            break;
        case 'InvoiceLineItems':
            $partnerInfo = $this->partnerInfo->getPartnerInfo($id);
            $invoiceLineItems = $this->invoiceLineItems->getInvoiceLineItems($id);
            include 'view/invoice.php';
            break;
    }
}
```

However, the include statement found in `case 'InvoiceLineItems:'` appends the content of `invoice.php` to the bottom of the existing page rather than replacing it altogether. I've tried adding a target to the anchor, but that didn't work. How do I get the link to open the new page?

**UPDATE:** based on @sixeightzero suggestion, here is the call to retrieve();

```
        if (isset($_REQUEST['id'])) {

            //          A request ID value indicates arrival here through link.
            $this->retrieve('InvoiceLineItems',
                    $_REQUEST['id']);
        }
```

Also, I tried using a header redirect.

```
ob_start();
header('Location: /view/invoice.php', 302);
ob_end_flush();
exit();
```

It redirects, but I lose access to my array variables from

```
$invoiceLineItems = $this->invoiceLineItems->getInvoiceLineItems($id);
```

So, I get errors like

`Notice: Undefined variable: partnerInfo in C:\xampp\htdocs\bp\view\invoice.php on line 25`

and

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\bp\view\invoice.php on line 25`

Comment: Can you provide more of your code, specifically that which outputs prior to your switch statement?

Comment: Did my solution solved your problem??

Comment: @SHAKIRSHABBIR i don't know, yet. i'm out of the office all week. i'll let you know once i get back to it. thanks for the follow up.

Comment: I finally resolved it. I ended up using sessions to pass the arrays. Thanks everyone for helping.

Answer (score 0):

put exit(); at the end of the function to stop executing code after calling it.

or better still use invoice.php to display the invoices instead of the current page.

Comment: I am calling invoice.php. Its content is appended to invoiceList.php which gets displayed at the start of the app. Calling exit() after the include had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Since, you are using **super global** *$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']*, the
>   anchor will always direct to the same page.
>
> 2) Now, I assume, you call the **function** *retrieve()* at the end of
>   the page which in turn, after you hit the link, appends
>   'view/invoice.php' to the page, so you see the appended content at the
>   end.

Now, you want **to get the link to open the new page, there are two ways**:

> 1) You *redirect the page to the page view/invoice.php* and there you
>   *call the function retrieve and include target="self"* in the anchor tag.
>
> Or
>
> 2) You *do what you are doing but include target="blank"* in the
>   anchor tag.

Comment: The first part, you are correct on both accounts. I thought using PHP_SELF would allow me to replace existing content, but it appears not. As for the redirects, neither work as intended. _self works the same with or without it. _blank pops a new window and then displays the same content as before.

Comment: Okay, got your point. See my next answer. Plz hold I am writing.

Comment: On #2 of the first part, I misspoke. I do not call retrieve at the end of the page. As mentioned above, that function resides in the model, not the view. So, I've made no progress on this issue at all. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

In order to **get the link to open as fresh content**, do as follows:

> 1) ***Add javascript to the page***. In the Html Head section add the
>   following lines:
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
> function hideMainContentDiv(){
>  document.getElementById("mainContent").setAttribute("style", "display:none");
> }
> </script>
> ```
>
> 2) ***Add the onclick attribute to the anchor tag*** as:
>
> ```
> <a onclick="hideMainContentDiv()">
> ```
>
> 3) Now, ***enclose the content of the page in***  and give it
>   id="mainContent" as:
>
> ```
> <div id="mainContent"> <!-- All your content --> </div>
> ```
>
> 4) At the end of the page when you have enclosed your content, ***add
>   another div and call your function retrieve*** as:
>
> ```
> <div id="newContent">
> <?php retrieve($class,$id); ?>
> </div>
> ```

**What this will do** is:

> - When you click the link, it will call the javascript and hide all    your existing page content in the div whose *id="mainContent"*.
> - When your *function retrieve()* will be    called, it will include 'view/invoice.php' which will show your new    content.
> - Your *old content has already been hidden by javascript* call.

*I hope this resolves your query.*

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, your solution did not resolve the issue. My view does not know what InvoiceLineItems' function retrieve() is. So, it cannot be called as you have stated. All my models are called only from the controller.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be sessions.

```
        case 'InvoiceLineItems':
            $partnerInfo = $this->partnerInfo->getPartnerInfo($id);
            $invoiceLineItems = $this->invoiceLineItems->getInvoiceLineItems($id);
            $_SESSION['partnerInfo'] = $partnerInfo;
            $_SESSION['invoiceLineItems'] = $invoiceLineItems;

            ob_start();
            header('Location: /view/invoice.php');
            ob_end_flush();
            exit();
            break;
```

I added the array data to two session variables in the controller. Then, in the view, I replaced the corresponding variable names -- `$partnerInfo` and `$invoiceLineItems` -- with their session equivalents `$_SESSION['partnerInfo']` and `$_SESSION['invoiceLineItems']`.